DynamoDB updateItem if attribute exists
I need to update 3 attributes of item in table, but update one of them only if other attribute exists:
old object =>
let input = {
    Key: {
      PK: {
        S: "xxx"
      },
      SK: {
        S: "yyy"
      }
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":ts": {
        N: Date.now() + ""
      },
      ":st": {
        S: "zzz"
      }
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#TS": "Timestamp",
      "#STS": "Status"
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET #TS = :ts, #STS = :st",
    TableName: "WhatsappMessenger"
};
let command = new UpdateItemCommand(input);

new object =>
let input = {
    Key: {
      PK: {
        S: "xxx"
      },
      SK: {
        S: "yyy"
      }
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":ts": {
        N: Date.now() + ""
      },
      ":st": {
        S: "zzz"
      }
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#TS": "Timestamp",
      "#STS": "Status",
      "#V1": "Value",
      "#V2": "Value"
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET #TS = :ts, #STS = :st, **???**",
    TableName: "WhatsappMessenger"
};
let command = new UpdateItemCommand(input);

what I need to paste to add this "#V1 = if (#V2) "aaa"" logic?
I do not want to call 2 times dynamodb for inserting additional data to item, maybe there is a method to do this?

This question is similar to: How to prevent creating a new item in UpdateItem if the item does not exist. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is no way to achieve what you want without using 2 API calls.
However, if one scenario is far more likely than the other, you could write the logic such that there is only 1 API call in the vast majority of cases.
